# Changing the back color of UltraCalenderCombo

Tags: c#

How to change the back color of a UltraCalenderCombo control?

Answer (score 0):

from [help.infragistics.com](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinSchedule.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSchedule.UltraCalendarCombo~Appearance.html):

```
// Set the background
this.ultraCalendarCombo1.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
```